# create binary columns in a dataframe from condition on its value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0,1,2,3], columns=['A','B','C'])
df.iloc[0,0] = 'a'
df.iloc[1,0] = 'b'
df.iloc[1,1] = 'c'
df.iloc[2,0] = 'b'
df.iloc[3,0] = 'c'
df.iloc[3,1] = 'b'
df.iloc[3,2] = 'd'
df

out :   A   B   C
   0    a   NaN NaN
   1    b   c   NaN
   2    b   NaN NaN
   3    c   b   d
```

And I would like to add new columns to it which names are the values inside the dataframe (here `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'`,and `'d'`). Those columns are binary, and reflect if the values `'a'`,`'b'`,`'c'`,and `'d'` are in the row.

In one picture, the output I'd like is:

```
        A   B   C    a   b   c   d
   0    a   NaN NaN  1   0   0   0
   1    b   c   NaN  0   1   1   0
   2    b   NaN NaN  0   1   0   0
   3    c   b   d    0   1   1   1
```

To do this I first create the columns filled with zeros:

```
cols = pd.Series(df.values.ravel()).value_counts().index
for col in cols:
    df[col] = 0
```

(It doesn't create the columns in the right order, but that doesn't matter)

Then I...use a loop over the rows and columns...

```
for row in df.index:
    for col in cols:
        if col in df.loc[row].values:
            df.ix[row,col] = 1
```

You'll get why I'm looking for another way to do it, even if my dataframe is relatively small (76k rows), it still takes around 8 minutes, which is far too long.

Any idea?

Comment: You're looking for `get_dummies`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `get_dummies`. Here I choose to use the `.str` [version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
(df.A + '|' + df.B + '|'  + df.C).str.get_dummies()
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  1  1
```